# Prevent page refresh when clicking a link in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've found a weird behavior in AngularJS when clicking links. My goal would be to prevent the page to refresh when the path is the same, and only the query string changes.

The strange thing is that this happens already... but only sometimes. At least in my particular scenario, some links trigger the page refresh, and some others simply not, even when they look the same (except minor changes like ones having a title attribute and others not).

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="https://.../search?_target=event&...>Edit</a>
```

Besides this odd thing, which perhaps is the result of me doing something wrong, I would like to ask for the common way of avoiding page refresh on link clicks, and if possible when someone manually changes the URL, but only the query string. It's annoying to have to wait for the whole app to load just because you wanted to activate some particular pop-up, for instance.

Note that I have the HTML5 mode enabled.

Thanks.

Comment: The old fashioned way was to use href="#", which is a blank bookmark to the same page.

Comment: You mean to put both ng-href and href, the first one with the actual link and the latter with just a hash? But Angular overrides the href attribute afterwards, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you provide the DOM of your link? is probably just a `/` to much and it keeps reloading

Comment: I'm using UI Router already, I don't know what you meant by that, @Shaun. Regarding the DOM, I had a look at it and both links (href attribute) are exactly the same: none of them have the last slash, so they end like this: .../search?...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using absolute links in your `<a>` tags.

You should use your router's links (if you're using ui-router it's `ui-sref` to navigate state).

[EDIT]
The problem seems to be a lot different, so here's another wording:

"I need to display a popup based on my state params in all of my states, whenever my state changes".

So here's how to do it:

The logic says that since you have to display this in all of your state changes, you should hook a `$stateChangeSuccess` function ([docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)).

That way, you can implement your logic there and display pop-ups and everything. I suggest you put this into your `app.js` file or if the app is relatively large in some `events.js` file or whatever you prefer

```
angular.module('your_app_name').run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            // you have your toParams, your toState and everything here, so use your logic to open your popup window.
    })
});
```

Comment: To be precise, I want to be able to open a certain view (a pop-up), no matter in which page I am. That's why you can see a "_target" attribute in my example link, to select the particular pop-up that should be opened. Then, I'm checking the URL the first time the application (and the controller) is loaded, and listening to $locationChangeSuccess events to react to later changes. So I don't want to link the mentioned view to any particular state. (You pointed to the ngRoute documentation, by the way.)

Comment: So if I understand correctly you need to open a popup in EVERY state of your app. Does the state change the popup in some ways or is it always the same?

Comment: You understood it correctly. The pop-up indeed changes. We can say I have basically four of them, to display two kind of resources; for each resource, the pop-up may either display its information or a form to edit it. The URL contains all the information to achieve that: a _target (the type of resource) and an _action (either view or edit).

Comment: Ok I understand. The problem now seems a lot different so check out my edit

Comment: Sorry @Shaun, but the link does contain a "_target" part in the query string (that is almost the only thing it contains).

Comment: Your suggestion, @XelharK, is to change from $locationChangeSuccess to $stateChangeSuccess, isn't it? I don't exactly understand your answer, or why you decided to alter my question. I was just telling a little bit more about my case to clarify things, but I can already listen to URL changes properly, and respond to them with whatever logic I need. However, still, when some (only some) links are clicked, the page (and Angular) is reloaded. In both cases the application responds correctly, but when page is refreshed, one must wait for the whole application to be loaded.

Comment: No worries, I'll leave it. _target is an anchor attribute hence my confusion. All seems a bit odd.